# C# Connection String using IP in wamp server

Tags: c#, connection-string, wampserver, static-ip-address

So here's the scenario:

I can now access wamp server using other connected Lan Computers by using my IP Address,

I develop a program and use this Connection String

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;database=sampledatabase;userid=root;password=");
```

this Connection works,

Now my Problem is, I attempt to use the program in other Lan computers, I got error because it listens to their default localhost, So i change the connection string to a static IP 
 `MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=192.168.1.21,80;userid=root;password=");`

Now I got problem too, this doesnt work to my program, How can i fix my connection string using my IP? Please help thanks

Comment: I also used server=127.0.0.1 as well, definitely works, and change it to my ip, doesnt work.. Do i need to change the ip in wamp server?

Comment: What about the ', 80' in your connection string, are you trying to use a custom port? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Edited http.conf in wamp server, i just listen to 192.168.1.21:80 and listen to localhost, but in program i get an error when trying to use my ip and port instead of using localhost

Comment: NO, i dont use a custom port

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow remote connection to mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)